# What is “lightning downloader”

Tags: malware, download-manager

By a mistake I installed this on my system. Fast google search gave some sites that mark it as a malware etc and provide removal tools. However a fast google search about those sites shows that they aren't to be trust and probably scam.

Can anybody please help me with real info about this utility, and how to remove it safely?

EDIT: After I read [this topic](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc), I see that if it's malware, I'll reinstall my system, but My question is yet: Is it a malware, scam etc, or is it just a not efficient program?

Comment: @dave No. I'm asking about specific program whether it is malware or not. Thou I'll check this link. Thanks.

Comment: Is it malware?  That depends on your definition of malware.  It is installed surreptitiously, records information about your usage which the company shares without your knowledge or approval, displays advertizing you didn't request, and it may download other unrequested software.  If you think that's bad, then it's malware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightning Downloader is a downloader which infects computer with installing free programs. Except for main function this program can show advertisment and download other unwanted software supplied by cooperating companies.

As you're already aware, you should uninstall it along with all other software installed by it, or just reinstall OS.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please tell a little bit more about "download other unwanted software". Is it only when it is launched? Or does it work in the background? And my main question about harmfulness of this: does it itself harmful like a virus & malware and must be cleaned up (by new OS, as cleaning malware isn't helpful), or if I didn't run it yet I can just uninstall it and it will be like nothing happened?

Comment: It's a kind of "annoying but yet legal" software. So it installs several types of adversiting programs (ad plugins for different browsers, desktop ads etc.), but it won't (at least shouldn't) install really harmful software, steal anything etc.